# Accessing HTML Table after horizontal break

Tags: html, vba, excel

I fill out a web form using VBA as seen here:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Command()

Dim IE As Object
Dim tbls, tbl, trs, tr, tds, td, chkBox, check
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/oginfo/pipeline/pipeline2.asp"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4


Set chkBox = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
' Select Check Boxes
    For Each check In chkBox
        'If check.Name = "allbox" Then
        If check.Name = "paychecktable" Then
            check.Click
        End If
'Enter the Permit Number
        If check.Name = "prmtenter" Then
            check.Value = "05588"
        End If
    Next

With IE
' Enter the counter number into the drop down menu
    .Document.forms("form1").Item("cntyenter").Value = "33"
    .Document.forms("form1").Item("submit").Click
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
End With

'Dim tbody, p, i As Long, body
'
'Set p = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("body")(200)
'
'MsgBox p.innerText

'Set tbl = p.getElementsByTagName("table")
'Set tbody = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)
'Set tr = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")
'
'MsgBox tr.Length


End Sub
```

Which runs fine.
Now the problem is that I need to access an HTML table that is generated below a Horizontal break however VBA only recognizes three HTML tables which corresponds to the HTML above the horzontal break.. IE

```
<html>
<head><title>WVGES O&G Record Reporting System</title>

<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="text3.css">



<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
TABLE.main {border: 0px solid #000000; background-color: transparent; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;} 
-->
</STYLE>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function zoomToSite() {
    county = form1.cntyenter.value*100000;
    permit = form1.prmtenter.value*1;
    state = 4700000000*1;
    apinum = (state + county + permit)*1;

    var strURL = "http://ims.wvgs.wvnet.edu/wvog1/viewer.htm?ActiveLayer=11&Query=API%3D"+apinum+"&QueryZoom=Yes&Layers=011111100001000" 
window.open(strURL,"whatever","");
                 }
//-->
</SCRIPT>


<script language="JavaScript">  
<!--                              
 function variable_in_link(varible_value)   
 {                                           
 new_win = window.open(href='http://ims.wvgs.wvnet.edu/wvog/viewer.htm?ActiveLayer=12&Query=API%3D'+varible_value+'&QueryZoom=Yes&Layers=0000111100001000')   
   }      
 // -->     
   </script>  




<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
   <!-- hide script from old browsers

   function validate(form1) {

var wHeight,wWidth,sHeight,sWidth,bitDepth;

sHeight = screen.height;
sWidth = screen.width;
bitDepth = screen.colorDepth;


browserversion="0";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("2.") != -1) {browserversion="2"};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("3.") != -1) {browserversion="3"};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("5.") != -1) {browserversion="5"};
if ((navigator.appVersion.indexOf("4.7") != -1) && (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')) {browserversion="4"};
if ((navigator.appVersion.indexOf("4.8") != -1) && (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')) {browserversion="4"};
if ((navigator.appVersion.indexOf("4.9") != -1) && (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')) {browserversion="4"};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("6.") != -1) {browserversion="6"}; 


 if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && browserversion < 5) {
   wHeight = window.clientHeight;
   wWidth = window.clientWidth;
   }
 else {
   wHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
   wWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
      }


document.cookie = "wHeight=" + wHeight + ";";
document.cookie = "wWidth=" + wWidth + ";";
document.cookie = "sHeight=" + sHeight + ";";
document.cookie = "sWidth=" + sWidth + ";";
document.cookie = "bitDepth=" + bitDepth + ";";


   form1.jscheck.value="data";

   permit=form1.prmtenter.value;
   loc=form1.locchecktable.checked; 
   own=form1.ownchecktable.checked; 
   pay=form1.paychecktable.checked;
   prd=form1.prdchecktable.checked; 
   str=form1.strchecktable.checked; 
   mlc=form1.mlcchecktable.checked;
   plg=form1.plgchecktable.checked; 
   wsc=form1.wscchecktable.checked; 
  bhloc=form1.bhlocchecktable.checked;

  if ((loc == false) && (own == false) && (pay == false) && (prd == false) && (str == false) && (mlc == false) && (plg == false) && (bhloc == false) && (wsc == false)) {

   alert('You must select at least one datatype');

   return false;

    }


   if (permit > 0  && permit < 100000) {
      }
    else {
    alert('You must enter a Number Value for Permit # between 1 and 99999');


    return false;
    }   



}
//-->
</SCRIPT>



<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- document.form1.allbox.onclick = un_check; //-->
function un_check(){
  for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.elements.length; i++) {
    var e = document.form1.elements[i];
    if ((e.name != 'allbox') && (e.type == 'checkbox')) {
e.checked = document.form1.allbox.checked;
    }
  }
}
</SCRIPT>



</head>


   <BODY class=stuff marginheight="0" topmargin="0" vspace="0" marginwidth="0" leftmargin="0" hspace="0" style="margin:1; padding:1">

<table class=dog cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><TD align=left valign=top> 

 <img src="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/www/general/logorrr2.gif" width="128" height="66" align="left" alt="WVGES">
<br clear=left>
<center><font size=3><b>"Pipeline"<b></font><center></td>

<td width=5>&nbsp;</td>

<td>
<form name="form1" onSubmit="return validate(this);"  method=post  action="pipeline2.asp">
<input type=hidden name=jscheck value="">

<table width=475 class=cat valign=top>
<tr height=15><td width=150 valign=top ><nobr>Select County:  
<select name="cntyenter" size=1> </nobr>
<Option value="1"    >(001) Barbour
<Option value="3"    >(003) Berkeley
<Option value="5"    >(005) Boone
<Option value="7"    >(007) Braxton
<Option value="9"    >(009) Brooke
<Option value="11"   >(011) Cabell
<Option value="13"   >(013) Calhoun
<Option value="15"   >(015) Clay
<Option value="17"   >(017) Doddridge
<Option value="19"   >(019) Fayette
<Option value="21"   >(021) Gilmer
<Option value="23"   >(023) Grant
<Option value="25"   >(025) Greenbrier
<Option value="27"   >(027) Hampshire
<Option value="29"   >(029) Hancock
<Option value="31"   >(031) Hardy
<Option value="33"  selected >(033) Harrison
<Option value="35"   >(035) Jackson
<Option value="37"   >(037) Jefferson
<Option value="39"   >(039) Kanawha
<Option value="41"   >(041) Lewis
<Option value="43"   >(043) Lincoln
<Option value="45"   >(045) Logan
<Option value="47"   >(047) McDowell
<Option value="49"   >(049) Marion
<Option value="51"   >(051) Marshall
<Option value="53"   >(053) Mason
<Option value="55"   >(055) Mercer
<Option value="57"   >(057) Mineral
<Option value="59"   >(059) Mingo
<Option value="61"   >(061) Monongalia
<Option value="63"   >(063) Monroe
<Option value="65"   >(065) Morgan
<Option value="67"   >(067) Nicholas
<Option value="69"   >(069) Ohio
<Option value="71"   >(071) Pendleton
<Option value="73"   >(073) Pleasants
<Option value="75"   >(075) Pocahontas
<Option value="77"   >(077) Preston
<Option value="79"   >(079) Putnam
<Option value="81"   >(081) Raleigh
<Option value="83"   >(083) Randolph
<Option value="85"   >(085) Ritchie
<Option value="87"   >(087) Roane
<Option value="89"   >(089) Summers
<Option value="91"   >(091) Taylor
<Option value="93"   >(093) Tucker
<Option value="95"   >(095) Tyler
<Option value="97"   >(097) Upshur
<Option value="99"   >(099) Wayne
<Option value="101"  >(101) Webster
<Option value="103"  >(103) Wetzel
<Option value="105"  >(105) Wirt
<Option value="107"  >(107) Wood
<Option value="109"  >(109) Wyoming
</select></td>

<td width = 275 colspan=3><b>Select datatypes:</b> <input type=checkbox  name=allbox value="bill" onclick=un_check()><b>(Check All)</b></td></tR>


<tr height=15><td >Enter Permit #: <input type=text name="prmtenter" size=10 value="05588"</td></td>

<td rowspan=2>
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="locchecktable" value="yes"  >Location</nobr><br />
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="ownchecktable" value="yes"  >Owner/Completion</nobr><br />
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="paychecktable" value="yes" checked >Pay/Show/Water</nobr><br /></td>



<td rowspan=2>
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="prdchecktable" value="yes"  >Production</nobr><br />
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="strchecktable" value="yes"  >Stratigraphy</nobr><br />
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="mlcchecktable" value="yes"  >Logs</nobr><br /></td>


<td rowspan=2>
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="plgchecktable" value="yes"  >Plugging</nobr><br />
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="wscchecktable" value="yes"  >Sample</nobr><br />
<nobr><input type=checkbox name="bhlocchecktable" value="yes"  >Btm Hole Loc</nobr><br />

</td></tr>



<tr height=25><td><input type="submit"  name=submit value="Get Data">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


<INPUT TYPE="RESET" Value="Reset" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>          


</td>
</tr></table>
<td width=5>&nbsp;</td>

<td width=50 valign=center>
<a href="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/oginfo/pipeline/tabledesc/ogdesc.html"><nobr>Table Descriptions</nobr></a><br>
<a href="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/oginfo/pipeline/cntycode.html"><nobr>County Code Translations</nobr></a><br>
<a href="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/oginfo/pipeline/series.html"><nobr>Permit-Numbering Series</nobr></a><br>
<a href="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/oginfo/pipeline/usage_notes.html"><nobr>Usage Notes</nobr></a><br>
<a href="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/oginfo/pipeline/contact.html"><nobr>Contact Information</nobr></a><br>
<a href="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/oginfo/pipeline/pipeline2.asp">Disclaimer</a>&nbsp;<br>
<a href="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/www/index.html"><nobr>WVGES Main</nobr></a><br>
<nobr><a href="http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/pipe2/OGWISHelp.aspx">&#34;Pipeline-Plus&#34;</a><font color=red> New</font></nobr><br>




</td></tr></table>


<hr>


<!-- <table style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF; background-color: transparent;" width=99%><tr><td width=50%> West Virginia Geological & Economic Survey </td>
<td width=30% align=right>
Report Time:  Monday, September 14, 2015&nbsp;&nbsp;2:56:49 PM</td></tr></table>
//-->




<table class=dog width=99&#37;><tr><td width=40&#37;> WV Geological & Economic Survey: </td><td width =30&#37;> <font size=3><B>Well: &nbsp;   County = 33 Permit = 05588</b></font><td width=30&#37; align=right> Report Time: &nbsp;&nbsp;Monday, September 14, 2015  2:56:49 PM</td></tr></table><p>Pay/Show/Water Information: <BR><table  cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR><TD><B>API</b></td><TD><B>CMP_DT</b></td><TD><B>ACTIVITY</b></td><TD><B>PRODUCT</b></td><TD><B>SECTION</b></td><TD><B>DEPTH_TOP</b></td><TD><B>FM_TOP</b></td><TD><B>DEPTH_BOT</b></td><TD><B>FM_BOT</b></td><TD><B>G_BEF</b></td><TD><B>G_AFT</b></td><TD><B>O_BEF</b></td><TD><B>O_AFT</b></td><TD><B>WATER_QNTY</b></td></tr><tr><td align=right><nobr>4703305588</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>8/30/2012</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Fresh Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Vertical</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>20</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Pennsylvanian System</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td></tr><tr><td align=right><nobr>4703305588</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>8/30/2012</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Fresh Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Vertical</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>23</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Pennsylvanian System</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td></tr><tr><td align=right><nobr>4703305588</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>8/30/2012</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Fresh Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Vertical</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>40</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Pennsylvanian System</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td></tr><tr><td align=right><nobr>4703305588</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>8/30/2012</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Fresh Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Vertical</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>45</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Pennsylvanian System</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td></tr><tr><td align=right><nobr>4703305588</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>8/30/2012</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Fresh Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Vertical</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>50</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Pennsylvanian System</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td></tr><tr><td align=right><nobr>4703305588</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>8/30/2012</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Salt Water</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Vertical</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>1510</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Mississippian</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td></tr><tr><td align=right><nobr>4703305588</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>8/30/2012</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Pay</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Gas</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Deviated</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>8127</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Marcellus Sh</nobr></td><td align=right><nobr>14874</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr>Marcellus Sh</nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td><td align=left><nobr></nobr></td></tr></table><p>


</form>



</body>
</html>
```

The final Table after the horizontal break

---

is what I need to access however no matter what I try I can't seem to access it. It would seem that I would need VBA to recognize that the page has loaded in turn giving it access to the newly generated HTML which is displayed on the exact same website URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following waits until there are at least 4 tables in the `.Document` before proceeding.

```
Dim dTill As Double
With IE
' Enter the counter number into the drop down menu
    .Document.forms("form1").Item("cntyenter").Value = "33"
    .Document.forms("form1").Item("submit").Click
    Do While IE.busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    dTill = Timer + 5 'maximum of 5 seconds to keep looking
    Do While dTill > Timer And .Document.getElementsByTagName("table").Length < 4
        Debug.Print .Document.getElementsByTagName("table").Length
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Debug.Print .Document.getElementsByTagName("table").Length
    Debug.Print .Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(2).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innertext
    Debug.Print .Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innertext

End With
```

A maximum of a 5 second wait has been instituted in order that you are not waiting forever for something that will not show up. The `.Length` (or number of) property is 1 based (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc) while the index position of the element in the collection is 0 based (e.g. 0, 1, 2, etc). The table that reports the datetime of the report is discarded but that should not be important since it is simply spitting back the current Now in eastern time (UTC-05).

The table with the `API CMP_DT ACTIVITY PRODUCT, etc` data is at index position 3. You can loop through the `<td>`'s in the first `<tr>` for the column labels and every other row for the data.

Comment: Be careful using `Timer`. It is the number of seconds since midnight and resets every midnight. So at 23:59:58 it is going to be 86,398 and in 5 seconds it will be 3. If you do not have correction built in, you run the possibility of entering into a forever loop (but the table load would have to fail as well).

Comment: interesting, I will keep this in mind the key concept that I was missing was that I needed to wait long enough for the java script to generate the html table making it accessible to VBA. Thus you don't actually need timer at all, you just need to artificially wait x amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

For your given HTML you can use a CSS selector for the element and loop while is nothing to give page time to load.

CSS selector: `table:not(.dog):not(.cat)`

This is element with `table` tag that does not contain class of `cat` or `dog`.

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA Code:**

You probably want to add a time-out to prevent infinite looping.

```
Do 
   DoEvents
   On Error Resume Next
   Set a = IE.document.querySelector("table:not(.dog):not(.cat)")
   On Error GoTo 0

Loop While a Is Nothing
```